# Field statusUpdateService in spring.controller.pageController required a bean of type 'service.StatusUpdateService' that could not be foun

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-applications

my web app failed to start , here the console error:
something with the autowird not working, i need to add something along with autowird?
before that everthing worked fine.

i am using the latest version of mysql,spring,java and etc...

```
    2020-03-23 11:25:56.481 DEBUG 12284 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : Application failed to start due to an exception

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'service.StatusUpdateService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at spring.App.main(App.java:17) ~[classes/:na]

2020-03-23 11:25:56.482 ERROR 12284 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field statusUpdateService in spring.controller.pageController required a bean of type 'service.StatusUpdateService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'service.StatusUpdateService' in your configuration.
```

this is my pageController:

```
package spring.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import service.StatusUpdateService;
import spring.model.StatusUpdate;


@Controller
public class pageController {

    @Autowired
    private StatusUpdateService statusUpdateService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "app.homepage";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/about")
    String about() {
        return "app.about";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addstatus", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    ModelAndView addstatus(ModelAndView modelAndView) {

        modelAndView.setViewName("app.addstatus");

        StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate();

        StatusUpdate latestStatusUpdate = statusUpdateService.getLatest();


        modelAndView.getModel().put("statusUpdate", statusUpdate);
        modelAndView.getModel().put("latestStatusUpdate", latestStatusUpdate);

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addstatus", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    ModelAndView addstatus(ModelAndView modelAndView, StatusUpdate statusUpdate) {

        modelAndView.setViewName("app.addstatus");

        statusUpdateService.save(statusUpdate);

        StatusUpdate latestStatusUpdate = statusUpdateService.getLatest();
        modelAndView.getModel().put("latestStatusUpdate", latestStatusUpdate);


        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

and this is my StatusUpdateService:

> package service;
>
> ```
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
> import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
>
> import spring.model.StatusUpdate;
> import spring.model.StatusUpdateDao;
>
> @Service
> public class StatusUpdateService {
>
>   @Autowired
>   private StatusUpdateDao statusUpdateDao;
>
>   public void save(StatusUpdate statusUpdate) {
>       statusUpdateDao.save(statusUpdate);
>   }
>
>   public StatusUpdate getLatest() {
>       return statusUpdateDao.findFirstByOrderByAddedDesc();
>   }
> ```
>
> }

what can be the problem?
thank you

Comment: Saying you're using the latest versions of certain software isn't very accurate. For example the latest stable Java version (14) isn't officially supported by Spring yet.

Comment: I mean the managed versions